# RxJS authentication timeout

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm relatively new to Angular 2 and RxJS, and I've got a question about how to set up an observable. I've got a REST HTTP API that provides authentication, the big part of which is if a timeout occurs between REST calls, the user is un-authenticated.

On the client I'd like to create an Observable for the REST HTTP call (essentially an Angular 2 service). This is tied to a timer. So long as another REST HTTP call occurs within the timeout, the logged_in value remains true. If the timeout expires, the logged_in value goes to false. So what I need is a way for the REST HTTP call to reset the timer so it restarts.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of general patterns, you might benefit from using [ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store) for centralized application state management (state, actions, reducers) in combination with [ngrx/effects](https://github.com/ngrx/effects) for dealing with "side-effects" like REST-API calls.

An "official" example app can be found here: [ngrx/example-app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/tree/master/src)

It is worth exploring in general if you intend to build complex Angular 2 apps with a reactive (functional) approach.

Specific to your case, between

- a slice of the **store** `State` that captures your login status,
- **actions** related starting login, login success action, login failure action, and
- the **effect** that wraps the API call for authentication and is triggered by the start login action

you should have a good framework in place to address managing log-in state. Your services/components can then use observables of slices of the store state to respond to state changes. Then you can use all the powerful RxJs operators to map, compose etc.

So adding in additional aspects like triggering actions related to "timeout" or retry can be added to the basic flow of events.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll take a look at ngrx/store and try to get up to speed on it.